# Execute js after all image loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, load

*(I searched, but not find exactly/easy solution)* 
I'm trying to execute JS after all images completely loaded. My goal is, when all images finish load completely, then removeClass `my-loader` and addClass `visible` to `main-slider` div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='main-slider my-loader'>
<img src="/nice-girl.jpg">
<img src="/nice-car.jpg">
<img src="/nice-boy.jpg">
</div>
```

**Execute below js when all images completely loaded**

```
$(".main-slider").removeClass("my-loader").addClass("visible");
```

**Tried** :  
But not work, problem is it execute before complete image load:

```
var imagesPre = new Array;
var success = new Array;

$('.big-slides img').each(function(){
  imagesPre.push(this.src);
});

for (i = 0; i < imagesPre.length; i++) {
    (function(path, success) {
        image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
          success.resolve();
        };
        image.src = path;
    })(imagesPre[i], success[i] = $.Deferred());
}

$.when.apply($, success).done(function() {
$(".main-slider").removeClass("my-loader").addClass("visible"); 
});
```

Any ideia for simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `load()` to check if the images are loaded!

```
$('.imgTag').each(function(){
  $(this).load(function(){
   $(".main-slider").removeClass("my-loader").addClass("visible"); 
  })
})
```

This may not work sometimes when the images are cached by the browser. Please check [`Caveats of the load event when used with images`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```js
var img = $('img')
var count = 0
img.each(function(){
  $(this).load(function(){
    count = count + 1
    if(count === img.length) {
      $('.main-slider').removeClass('my-loader').addClass('visible')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-slider my-loader'>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random">
</div>
```

But, this answer is a working case.

Comment: @Aariba Updated the answer.Check!

Comment: `$(".main-slider").removeClass("my-loader").addClass("visible"); ` not execute.

Comment: @Aariba Did you check the updated example? It's working ryt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124710/discussion-between-aariba-and-pranesh-ravi).

Comment: @Aariba Added a perfect working example. try to inspect and see the class change.

Comment: let me check please

Comment: @Aariba You can't do anything about it! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='main-slider my-loader'>
<img class="imgTag" src="/nice-girl.jpg">
<img class="imgTag" src="/nice-car.jpg">
<img class="imgTag" src="/nice-boy.jpg">
</div>

jquery codes:
`
window.loadCount = 0;
$('.imgTag').onload(function(){
    window.loadCount++;
    if(window.loadCount == $('.imgTag').length){
        $('.imgTag').show();
    }
});
`
```

Comment: the code syntax may be incorrect because i wrote it fast but its algorithm is correct

Comment: replace "onload" by "load" and test