# Execute js after all image loaded not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, load

*(not duplicate, because not find exactly/easy solution)* 
I'm trying to execute JS after all images completely loaded. My goal is, when all images finish load completely, then removeClass `my-loader` and addClass `visible` to `main-slider` div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='main-slider my-loader'>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/">
</div>
```

**Execute below js when all images completely loaded**

```
$(".main-slider").removeClass("my-loader").addClass("visible");
```

**Tried this js** :  
But not works properly on my site, problem is when i clear browser cache, then it works/execute! when i reload page then next time it's not works/execute! 
 It only works when i  clear browser cache.

```
var img = $('.main-slider img')
var count = 0
img.each(function(){
  $(this).load(function(){
    count = count + 1
    if(count === img.length) {
      $('.main-slider').removeClass('my-loader').addClass('visible')
    }
  });
});
```

Any simple solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute js after all image loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806719/execute-js-after-all-image-loaded)

Comment: Why not just `$(window).on('load'` instead

Comment: not works, tried....

Comment: The "?random" must be a real random number... in this way never use the cache browser.

Comment: Images link updated.

Comment: Check out this link for tips on how not to load images from the browser cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides a way to register a callback for the window load event which will fire when the entire page, including images and iframes, are loaded. 
Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Your code should look something like:

```
$( window ).load(function () {
  var img = $('.main-slider img')
  var count = 0
  img.each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
      count = count + 1
      if(count === img.length) {
        $('.main-slider').removeClass('my-loader').addClass('visible')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is correct but at this point it is no longer necessary to check whether the images have been loaded, simply remove the class in the event "window.load".

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this, using Deferreds and native handlers, and calling the `onload` handler if the image is cached in older browsers etc.

```
var img  = $('.main-slider img');
var defs = img.map(function(){
    var def = new Deferred();

    this.onload  = def.resolve;
    this.onerror = def.reject;
    if (this.complete) this.onload();

    return def.promise();
});

$.when.apply($, defs).then(function() {
    $('.main-slider').removeClass('my-loader').addClass('visible')
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your cache, so then you're doing something else wrong.